# 6bit ORgate Verilog

Tags: verilog

Would it be fair to say that the next line will work as a 6bit OR gate. So, when one of the 6 bits of "columns" is high that the variable "ORgate" will be high:

```
 assign  ORgate = columns[0] || columns[1] || columns[2] || columns[3] || columns[4] || columns[5];
```

Comment: `||` is a logical or, `|` Bitwise. They evaluate to the same thing here, Bitwise would have expressed your intent better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will, but there's a shorter way using "reduction operators":

```
 assign ORgate = |columns;
```